# Use fundamental identities to write the first expression in terms of the second, for any acute angle θ. sec(θ); sin(θ)

Tags: algebra-precalculus, trigonometry

Can someone please help me with the question above? I don't understand what it's asking. A thorough explanation would be much appreciated.

Answer (score 2):

Using the "fundamental" identity : $\sin^2 x + \cos^2 x = 1 $

$$ \sec^2 x  = \frac{1}{\cos^2 x} = \frac{1}{1 - \sin^2 x} $$

$$ \therefore \sec x = \frac{1}{ \sqrt{1 - \sin^2 x }} $$

Comment: What does it mean to write the first expression in terms of the second? and why did you start out with sec^2x? I understand the trig process that you used to simplify but I don't understand why you used that Pythagorean identity, and I don't understand how you know when you're finished?

Comment: It's worth mentioning that the choice $+ \sqrt{1 - \sin^2 x}$ is where we use that $\theta$ is actue.

Comment: I don't understand haha.